# Invoking a non-generic method which is declared in a base generic class throws exception with message

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, invoke, postsharp

Invoking a non-generic method which is declared in a base generic class throws exception with this message:

**"Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true"**

I have decent experience on reflection but the recent change I made in my code caused a very rare case which I can't figure out.

I researched the web for a long long time and I have tried many possible/suggested solutions but I couldn't find the solution for my rare case.

All of the examples on the web are providing solutions for generic methods but in my case, the method I try to invoke is NOT generic. The class which contains the method is NOT generic. The class inherits a base class and only this base class IS generic.

Can anyone please give me any idea about correctly invoking a non-generic method which belongs to a non-generic class which inherits from a generic base class?

I'll try to isolate the problem and provide sample code which's highly trimmed so you can see what I mean.

**Sidenote:** Please don't suggest me to change my approach. I have to do this via Reflection and this class structure can't change. I'm trying to find a solution to this very specific case. Please don't be the person who don't know the specific answer but tries to convince me to change my approach.

```
// Execution starts here in some code piece.
// We don't know the type of Instance.
// It can either be SubClassA or SubClassB.
{
    // This finds the method correctly. It doesn't return null.
    MethodInfo ValidationMethod = Instance.GetType().GetMethod("Validate", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

    // This throws the exception with the message shown above.
    ValidationMethod.Invoke(Instance, null);
}

public class SubClassA : BaseClass<EventArgs>
{
}

public class SubClassB : BaseClass<CancelEventArgs>
{
}

public abstract class BaseClass<T>
{
    void Validate()
    {
        Debug.Log("Validating");
    }
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't be possible with the code you've shown. `Instance.GetType()` cannot return a type still requiring generic parameters, and the method doesn't take generic parameters either. Can you please put together a complete minimal program that demonstrates the error? There'll be something in there that's missing from your question right now.

Comment: When I run your code your GetMethod returns null. Can you make sure the code you put in the question accurately reproduces the issue you are having. You should be able to run the code you are giving us and get the exact same error. This means you should also declare Instance (eg `var Instance = new SubClassA();`).

Comment: In this example, you get a null exception, as @Chris says. I think this is because `GetMethod()` is not exposed via Reflection since a private member of an abstract class is unreachable. I'm not even sure if the compiler will emit the code. Anyway, if you change `void Validate()` to `protected void Validate()`, the code works as written.

Comment: @JohnWu: Ah yes, good point. So there is just not enough info here to reproduce the error. :(

Comment: Guys. Thank you for your comments. As I said, I tried to trim the code to be able to focus the exact problem, hoping that an experienced eye can see what I'm dealing with. Ok. As you guys suggested, I'll try to give you a bigger picture.

Comment: Can you guys please remove the downvotes?

I know you expected a better code piece which can be compiled but I guess it was enough in this state to get a correct answer. @TheGeneral helped me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments suggest, there is something missing from the question.

However all things being equal, this should work, the key is the `BaseType`

```
var subClassB = new SubClassB();

var ValidationMethod = subClassB.GetType()
                                .BaseType?
                                .GetMethod("Validate", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

ValidationMethod?.Invoke(subClassB, null);
```

Comment: Can you explain how this fixes the issue? At a glance this code seems to be addressing a problem with being unable to get the right MethodInfo but the OP indicated they were already getting a non-null method info ("This finds the method correctly. It doesn't return null.").

Comment: @Chris i agree fully and there is something missing, as the result should be null if its the base class issue. I don't mind removing the answer if OP figures it doesn't solve his problems though

Comment: Fair enough. It may well help. I was just confused because it didn't seem to be addressing the error as given (ie "Late bound operations...").

Comment: @Xtro if this doesn't solve your problem please let me know so i can remove it

Comment: OMG!! This worked. BaseType is the answer. I am surprised because I thought this was one of this things I tried when I was doing my research/debugging all day. I don't know how this slipped. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Xtro glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

Reflection isn't needed. The way you'd typically solve this is with a non-generic interface:

```
interface IBase
{
    void Validate();
}

public abstract class BaseClass<T> : IBase
{
    public void Validate()
    {
        Debug.Log("Validating");
    }
}

public class SubClassA : BaseClass<EventArgs>
{
}

public class SubClassB : BaseClass<CancelEventArgs>
{
}
```

To call `Validate()`, you'd use:

```
IBase o = Instance;
o.Validate();
```

[Example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Cl7gIQ).